# Remove flutter plugin from dependencies

Tags: flutter, plugins

I wanna delete the flutter toast plugin that I have in my project.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
```

How to remove it safety? I want to:

- delete this line **fluttertoast: ^8.0.9** from **pubspec.yaml** file
- delete this piece of code in **pubspec.lock**

```
fluttertoast:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: fluttertoast
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "8.0.9"
```

- remove unused flutter toast imports in files

Is it ok? Or should I do it in another way?

Comment: just run flutter pub remove fluttertoast, type flutter pub -h for more info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Remove `fluttertoast` from your "pubspec.yaml" file and hit `flutter pub get` in the terminal and remove the imports from your project.

Or

2. Hit `flutter pub remove fluttertoast` in the terminal and remove the imports.

This should work.

Comment: Run flutter pub remove fluttertoast and remove imports works fine :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First remove `fluttertoast: ^8.0.9` and all the config in your `yamel` file, then remove all the `import` that you use in your dart files. After that run `flutter pub get`.